# Code Improvement for complex if else function with flexible function arguments

Tags: r

**Problem:** I have this rather complex function which I want to make more flexible. In particular, I will not know in advance how many `ce_*` and `td_*` there will be (there will always be at least `ce_1`, `td_0` and `td_1`). So, I want to keep the function arguments flexible and in the body I would like to replace the `else-if` statement in a somehow more flexible way.

**Remark:** The function will later on be called in a `data.table` object via `mapply` where the arguments will be columns of the data.

Any suggestions how to do that? Many thanks!!

```
determine_left_right <- function(current_date, 
                                 ce_1, 
                                 ce_2, 
                                 ce_3, 
                                 td_0, 
                                 td_1, 
                                 td_2, 
                                 td_3){

  ## check target_dates
  if (current_date <= td_0){
    return("right")

  ## these if-conditions are logically the same -------
  } else if ((current_date > td_0) & ((current_date <= td_1) | is.na(td_1))){
    if (is.na(ce_1) | (ce_1 > current_date)){
      return("left")
    } else if ((current_date >= ce_1) & (current_date <= td_1)){
      return("right")
    }

  } else if ((current_date > td_1) & ((current_date <= td_2) | is.na(td_2))){
    if (is.na(ce_2) | (ce_2 > current_date)){
      return("overdue")
    } else if ((current_date >= ce_2) & (current_date <= td_2)){
      return("right")
    }

  } else if ((current_date > td_2) & ((current_date <= td_3) | is.na(td_3))){
    if (is.na(ce_3) | (ce_3 > current_date)){
      return("overdue")
    } else if ((current_date >= ce_3) & (current_date <= td_3)){
      return("right")
    }
  ##  -------------------------------------------------

  } else if (current_date > td_3){
    return("left")
  } ## check target date done  

}

determine_left_right (current_date = Sys.Date(), 
                   ce_1 = as.Date("2020-05-02"),
                   ce_2 = as.Date("2020-05-04"),
                   ce_3 = NA,
                   td_0 = as.Date("2020-05-30"),
                   td_1 = as.Date("2020-06-01"),
                   td_2 = as.Date("2020-06-07"),
                   td_3 = NA
                   )
```

Comment: I think there's more mileage in refactoring your data than in writing a flexible function.  Suppose you had a `data.frame` or  `vector`s.  As a `data.frame`, you could have columns `Type` (with values `ce` and `td` and `Index` with values 1, 2, 3, 4...  With vectors `ce` and `td`, you just loop over their elements, after making sure they're the same length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I mean:

```
# Note the introduction of an NA at the start of the ce vector to align the elements correctly
ce <- c(NA, as.Date("2020-05-02"), as.Date("2020-05-04"), NA)
td <- c(as.Date("2020-06-01"), as.Date("2020-06-07"), as.Date("2020-06-07"), NA)

newFunc <- function(current_date=Sys.Date(), ce, td) {
  if (length(ce) != length(td)) stop("Bad lengths")
  if (length(ce) == 0) stop("No data")

  # if (current_date <= td[1]) return("right")
  # else if (current_date > td[length(td)-1]) return("left")
  for (i in 1:(length(ce)-1)) {
    if ((current_date > td[i]) & ((current_date <= td[i+1]) | is.na(td[i+1]))) {
      if (is.na(ce[i+1]) | (ce[i+1] > current_date)) return(ifelse(i==1, "left", "overdue"))
      else if ((current_date >= ce[i+1]) & (current_date <= td[i+1])) return("right")
    }
  }
}

newFunc(ce=ce, td=td)
```

This gives the same result as your demo code (`overdue`) but one test case isn't enough to validate the code for every possible situation.